# How dropdown find out that its selected index has changed and need to fire selected index changed event?

Tags: asp.net

How dropdown find out that its selected index has changed and need to fire selected index changed event?

Suppose i have a dropdown which is bounded with objectdatasource
and objectdatasource has following items 
opt1
opt2
opt3
opt4
then i added default value --select-- to objectdatasource, now dropdown is populated and i can see all the items on it. I have a button and on its client click, through java script i set opt4 to selected item. now if i select --select-- from dropdown then it does not fire selected index changed event but it fires dropdown's data bound event and then if i select any other value it fire both events and then if i again select --select-- then it fire both event, only first time if i select --select--then it will not fire selected index change event but if i select other than --select-- it fire both events.

So my question is how dorpdown find out that its selection index has changed.

Comment: Did not get you can you be more clear

Comment: @Dorababu: question is updated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OnSelectedIndexChanged should always fire on a DropDownList postback if includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint is true

System.Web.UI.Page

```
private void ProcessRequestMain(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) {
    if (includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint) {
        ...
        if (this.IsPostBack) {
            ...
            this.RaiseChangedEvents();


internal void RaiseChangedEvents() {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < this._changedPostDataConsumers.Count; i++) {
        ...
        postBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent();
    }
}
```

System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList

```
void IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
{
    this.RaisePostDataChangedEvent();
}

protected virtual void RaisePostDataChangedEvent() {
    ..
    this.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer plz.